# Routing issue in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have strange issue in laravel routing.When i am started the project using the CLI tools everything works fine,but try using webbrowser will get `NotFoundHttpException`.
Here is my code

**Routes**

```
Route::get('agent','AgentController@index');
```

**Controller**

```
class AgentController extends Controller {

    //controller for agents 
    public function index(){
        return view('agents/agent-profile');
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT**

1.when using Command `php artisan serve --port 8080` i can access `agent` pages like this way `localhost:8080/agent`

2.when using webbrowser directly via `localhost/project-folder/public/agent` i will get a `NotfoundException`.

My laravel version is 5.0.31,i am using xampp.

**htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Wouldn't the url from xampp be localhost/agent?

Comment: What about -> localhost/project-folder/public/index.php/agent

Comment: Its loaded but the style sheets is missing.how to remove index.php?

Comment: Enable your mod rewrite module to your apache on your xampp control panel

Comment: That should work fine? what happened? I already comment an answer :)

Comment: post your htaccess file.

Comment: are you using vhosts to setup virtual host?

Answer (score 0):

To remove index.php, copy these lines of code in .htaccess file in your public directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]


# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Its related to route.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your xampp controll panel -> Apache -> Config -> open httpd.conf

Find this line

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Uncomment it

Done

Answer (score 0):

Point your webserver to the `public` folder instead of `project-folder`

Comment: I have changed  `'url' => 'http://localhost/' to 'url' =>` to `http://localhost/project-folder` ,but didnt work

Comment: No, I mean in the vhost configuration of your webserver, where you point the domain to it's folder, set it to the public folder inside your project folder instead of the project folder itself

Answer (score 0):

Remove the public in the url. You can just use "localhost/project-folder/agent" because the root directory always points to "public"

Comment: Do you have a vhost configuration? You should point the root directory to public